# perl reading from file into hash failure

Tags: perl, input, hashmap, output, filehandle

I have a `perl` script that reads data from a file and then prints it to a custom color terminal on `linux`. It is reading the file one line at a time. The file contains messages about human attributes (`first name, last name, eye color`) followed by a hex message.

**Problem:** The problem occurs on the last attribute or when there is only one attribute in the file. It will read in the data and not print it to the custom terminal.

Here is an example of what I have in the file that does not work:

```
Message Type: Human Attribute   
First Name: John
Last Name: Snow
Eye color: brown
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
```

The last line in the hex message is the last line in the file.. Here is the code I am using:

```
package Lib::HumanAttributeMessageProcessing;

use Exporter;

@ISA = ('Exporter');
@EXPORT = qw(&readRecord &initializeReader);

sub initializeReader {
    $messageHandler = shift;
    $fileHandlers{$messageHandler} = shift;
}

sub readRecord {
    my $mH = shift;
    my $fH = $fileHandlers{$mH};
    my $remaingLine = $lastLines{$mH};
    $lastLines{$mH} = undef;
    my %jRecord = ();

unless ($remainingLine) {
    $lastLines{$mH} = undef;
return;
}

if ($remainingLine =~ /Message Type:\s+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/) {
    $jRecord{"TYPE"} = $1;
}

$state = 0;

while (<$fH>) {
    if (!state && /Message Type:\s+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/) {
        $jRecord{"TYPE"} = $1;
    } elsif (!state && /First Name:\s+([a-zA-Z_]+)/) {  
        $jRecord{"FIRSTNAME"} = $1;
    } elsif (!state && /Last Name:\s+([a-zA-Z_]+)/) {   
        $jRecord{"LASTNAME"} = $1;
    } elsif (!state && /EYECOLOR:\s+([a-zA-Z_]+)/) {    
        $jRecord{"EYECOLOR"} = $1;
    } elsif (/^a[a-f\d]{2}/) {
        chomp;
        $jRecord {"HEX"} .= $_ . " ";
        $state = 1;
    } elsif ($state){
        $lastLines{$mH} = $_;
        last;
    } else {
        print STDERR "SKIPPING LINE: $_\n";
    }
}

\%jRecord;
}
```

Ive noticed that it reads the last line in the hex message but never exits the while loop. This code is in its own file that is called HumanAttributeMessageProcessing.pm. It is called by another file that is a perl script. Here is the script code that is calling the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use lib "./";
use Lib::HumanAttributeMessageProcessing;
use FileHandle;

%count = ();
$log = shift @ARGV;

open PIPE "tail -f -n +0 $log |"
    or die "Cannot open pipe\n";

initializeReader("1", \*PIPE\n";
$count = 1;
STDOUT->autoflush;
PIPE->autoflush;

while(1)
{
    $record = readRecord("1");

    if(defined($record))
    {
        $MSGType = getMessageType($record);
        $count{sprintf, "%s", $MSGType}++;
        system("clear");
        print "Summary:\n";
        $total = 0;
        foreach $key (sort keys %count)
        {
            $value = $count{key};
            printf "# %-55s # %7s #\n", $key, $value;
            $total += $value;
            printf "# %-55s # %7s #\n", $total;
        }

    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please `use strict; use warnings;` in your Perl program. Syntax of your code is incorrect. `elseif` should be `elsif`.

Comment: My mistake, It should be elsif, I had to copy the code by hand. That is why this mistake happened.

Comment: you should still `use warnings;` and `use strict;`... Are you using this as a module in another script, or running it as a script itself? Please update your question with your expected output

Comment: The code was written before me. It has the current error so I am trying figure out what the problem is. The code does not have the use strict or use warnings. I have added additional information.

Comment: Are there multiple records, or just one? What separates the records?

Comment: The next record would begin directly below the last line with hex data on it. There are no empty lines between the records. My problem occurs in the case of multiple records or a single record. It does not print the data of the last record. It seems to get stuck in the while(<$fH>) loop. For simplicity sake, I made the example contain only one record.

Comment: I have also noticed in the example above. If I modify the file with the record data and add an extra empty line at the end of the file. Then it will print that record. Otherwise if there is no empty line at the end it will NOT print that record. Keep in mind it does this for the last record in the file (in my John Snow example it is the only record). I have tried using the chomp feature to verify if there was a "\n" at the end of the hex string. In the case where there was no additional empty line at the end of the file, chomp would still return a 1.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was the way it was reading in the record. It was waiting for the next message in order to exit the loop. The hex message reading would wait for the start of the next message (Message Type). Once it reached that it, it would memorize it and then exit. The code needs to be modified to be able to read the hex lines without relying on the first line from the next message.